# No kotlin.Math class in kotlin 1.2 as it is said in the documentation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have been dealing with kotlin multiplatform alot recently, and I totaly understand the nature of the development. Initially, I had my own expected Math class (in a common module) and I had actual classes in the JS and JVM environment.

Since I like to read the documentations, I found that the Math liblary has been added to the standard liblary since kotlin 1.2. this trouble me as I am using kotlin 1.2.51 and I get an error trying to access the class from kotlin.Math in my common module and any of my platform specific module.

What am I not geting? How do I get access to the kotlin.Math class in my common module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while (I even feel stupid). I found that the kotlin.math library in kotlin common modules was already added. The only difference was, it had no the 'Math.' predecessor as I am normally used to.

So, 
Math.round(x: Float) was just round(x: Float)
Math.sin(x: Float) was just sin(x: Float)

Answer (score 6):

The `Math`-class is deprecated and the deprecated-message contains:

> Use top-level functions from kotlin.math package instead.

(see also https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-math/index.html)

So somehow the answer of @mTak is right, even though it was not mentioned, that you should use the `kotlin.math.*`-import *instead* of your `Math`-class.

Alternatively, you can also import `kotlin.math.max`, etc. depending on which function you actually require.

The more I think of it: I don't know whether there ever was a `Math`-class in the jvm-variant of Kotlin (couldn't find anything regarding it) and so in a multiplatform project the `Math`-class-access probably should always have failed.

Comment: what do you mean *it was not mentioned*?

Comment: You wrote "Import it like this: `import kotlin.math.*`, but there is no `Math`-class in there. It's missing the information that the `Math`-class should rather be replaced with the method-accesses directly in `kotlin.math`, which are available for both JS and JVM.

Comment: You're right about all the extra info, but since there is no Math class I suggested the only other alternative that exists

Comment: That's fine (I didn't downvote you). But you know there is no `Math`-class in there. The OP may not know. You could add that information, otherwise your *"import **it**"* could be misinterpreted as: your class is in that package.

Comment: Anyway I don't think it would be misinterpreted since this is what Kotlin offers

Comment: first, I can not import as there is no Math class or kotlin.math as @Roland suggests in a common module

Comment: second. bsed on [https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html] the documentation said they added kotlin.math since kotlin 1.2. Initially it was not in a common module thats why I had my own Math class

Answer (score 2):

Import it like this: `import kotlin.math.*`

Comment: Is there a problem I should be aware of?

Comment: how the hell can I import it if its not there?

Comment: it is not Math. it is `kotlin.math`. If you're using Kotlin 1.2.51 **it is there**

Comment: available in kotlin common modules? if so, then there is something probably wrong with my kotlin stdlib

Comment: which ide are you using?

Comment: intelliJ idea 2017.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: In your ide write this line: `val a = sqrt(10.0)`. If the ide does not suggest to import `kotlin.math.sqrt` then you need an update.

Comment: it also works well in the kotlin/js environment as val a = js("Math").sqrt(10.0)

Comment: It is as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

In the Kotlin standard library math functions are provided as top-level functions in the `kotlin.math` package.

Therefore you need to import that package and then you'll be able to use functions from it, like `sin`, `sqrt` and so on.

```
import kotlin.math.*

val sqrt2 = sqrt(2.0)
```

You can also import functions one by one, e.g. `import kotlin.math.sqrt` or even call them fully qualified `val result = kotlin.math.sqrt(2.0)`

Comment: kotlin.math is not available in a common module

Comment: It should be. Check the dependency on `kotlin-stdlib-common` library. If it's there and you still do not see `kotlin.math` please report an issue here: http://kotl.in/issue

Comment: @andylamax Do you have any errors reported if you write the code example given above in your common module?